# Replace Object in a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have two string called "newObject" and "oldObject". I also have a NSMutableArray called "nsArray".

Now I wanna replace in "nsArray" the "oldObject" with "newObject". I found following code:

```
nsArray = [myMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:newObject];
```

But how can I figure out, what the objectAtIndex is?

Answer (score 2):

```
const NSUInteger index = [myMutableArray indexOfObject:oldObject];
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but I will become an warning: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned long *') with an expression of type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Nanog000 You want `NSUInteger` not `NSUInteger *`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't already know the index of your object, you can get it with:

```
NSUInteger index = [nsArray indexOfObject:oldObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in `replaceObjectAtIndex:` you have to specify the position ob the object what you want to replace. Remember its measured from 0 to ∞.

So if: `@["Apple", "Microsoft","YouTube"];`

```
index = 2;

object(String) = [myMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:"Twitter"]; 

 @["Apple", "Microsoft","Twitter"];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't tell if you're intending this answer to be in Swift or Objective-C, but it doesn't look valid for either. You've got objc NSArray literals, Swift Strings, and you seem to be attempting to assign the return value of replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject: to a variable but that method has a return type of void.